# wordpress: can't access backend while frontend works perfect

Tags: wordpress

Before 2 days there was a automatic update for wordpress, which I for my website.

When the update was over, I tried to access backend but I always get this message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_is_mobile() in /home/*******/public_html/wp-login.php on line 67
```

Can you give me any idea what to do, how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: You might get more help on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-wp-is-mobile.

Also i found this function [here](http://wpseek.com/wp_is_mobile/). You can just add it to your functions file.

Answer (score 0):

For Fast Solution add below code in functions.php

```
function wp_is_mobile() {
    static $is_mobile;

    if ( isset($is_mobile) )
        return $is_mobile;

    if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
        $is_mobile = false;
    } elseif ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== false // many mobile devices (all iPhone, iPad, etc.)
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false
        || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mobi') !== false ) {
            $is_mobile = true;
    } else {
        $is_mobile = false;
    }

    return $is_mobile;
}
```

I did that and now it works